# Can I use the same HTML5 browser storage, across different domains?

Tags: html, storage, local-storage, same-origin-policy

There are a couple of different approaches for choosing an HTML5 browser storage (IndexedDB, Web Storage), but from what I read in the spec, the "same origin policy applies".

Is there a way to keep data inside the browser and have it available from both www.domain1.com/myapp1 and www.domain2.com/myapp2?

Answer (score 2):

### Cross-Document Messaging

You can use a technique called cross-document messaging to accomplish this.  [There is an article here that outlines how to implement it](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/), but it's basically where two domains talk to each other and pass information instead of directly accessing their data store, which the HTML 5 spec prohibits.

Answer (score 1):

That seems fraught with peril, I'm going to say that there's something in the spec to prevent that. Otherwise you could inject bad data into someone elses app.