# javascript/jquery local app using json as my DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm quite new to javascript/jQuery/Json. i'm building myself a local app ( no client side for now). right now i have a simple form (inputs and submit) and would like to get the inputs from the user with javascrip/JQuery and then build a JSON object and store it on a file. i managed to get the inputs using jQuery ,and using JSON.strigify() i have a JSON object. only thing is that i dont know how to write to a file with JS. i searched for a solution and understand that i might need to use PHP for that as JS is not meant for changing files.
here is my code:

**HTML form:**

```
<form name="portfolio" id="portfolio" method="post" onsubmit="getform()">
     <p>General</p>
        Portfolio   Name: <input type="text" id="portfolioName" name="portfolioName"><br>
        Owner First Name: <input type="text" id="ownerFName" name="ownerFName"><br>
        Owner Last  Name: <input type="text" id="ownerLName" name="ownerLName"><br>
      <p>Risk Management</p>
        %stocks : <input type="text" id="stocksPerc" name="stocksPerc"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

**JS code**

```
function getform() {

    var portfolioName = document.portfolio.portfolioName.value;
    var ownerFname = document.portfolio.ownerFName.value;
    var ownerLname = document.portfolio.ownerLName.value;
    var stocksPerc = document.portfolio.stocksPerc.value;

    var myJsonObject =JSON.stringify({
        "general": {
            "portfolioName": portfolioName,
            "ownerFname": ownerFname,
            "ownerLname": ownerLname
        },
        "riskManagement": {
            "stocksPerc": stocksPerc
        }
    });


   alert(myJsonObject);


    event.preventDefault();
};
```

now in "myJsonObject" i have the JSON object which i would like to write to a local file.
later on i would like to read this file ,and maybe update some of the values there.

can someone please help me understand how do i write it to a file ?
you can try and load this [page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13165525/jsonTest/index.html) which runs my code. hope it works for you.

**note**: programming is my area of interest but i didnt study it ,i'm learning all by myself so i'm sorry if i askqdo things that make you blind for a moment :). also this is the first question i post here ,feel free to say if i need to improve.

Thanks
Sivan

**update + clarification** : Thanks for the answers guys ,localStorage is something i didnt know about. from what i understand about localStorage  its only good for working in a single domain/location. (i encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651068/can-i-use-the-same-html5-browser-storage-across-different-domains) on site). what if i want the option of running the app from different locations - lets say there will be only one person updating the JSON data, no need for sync/lock and stuff like that. right now my files (JS,JSON..) are saved in dropbox ,this is how i can use the app from different locations today , i dont have any other server.

**2'nd update** : i tried the localStorage solution i've been offered and even though its a great capability ,its not exactly what i'm looking for since i need the JSON data  available in more then one location (i'll be using my desktop and my laptop for instance).
i'd be glad if you have other suggestions.

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the HTML5 [localStorage API](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You will be able to store your JSON objects there and retrieve them. They will be stored as key-value pairs. You can't write to a file using JS AFAIK.

Comment: indeed ,JS is not for writing files. localStorage seems interesting idea but i also need the option of running the app from different locations/domains thus i need to have my JSON data approachable from all locations. no need for lock/sync for now since i'm the only one using this app.

Comment: Your solution using Dropbox is better than anything I can think of. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a file as storage, use `localStorage`: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html. If you need to save information on a session scope, you should use `sessionStorage`, mind though that the latter is not persistant.

An example of how you would use it:

```
var item = {
  "general": {
    "portfolioName": portfolioName,
    "ownerFname": ownerFname,
    "ownerLname": ownerLname
  },
  "riskManagement": {
    "stocksPerc": stocksPerc
  }
}
// set item, you should think up of a unique key for each item
localStorage.setItem('your-key', item);

// remove it if no longer needed, you don't have a lot of space
localStorage.removeItem('your-key');
```

Comment: Hi Alberto , thanks for your answer. i added local storage to my code and although i think its a great feature ,it doesn't really help me as i need to save data for a long time + use it in different locations ,not only on my desktop at home. i can't rely on different storage capacities of different brtowsers ,i'll need to save large amount of data etc..

Comment: Ok, then this isn't a suitable solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

Saving files is possible in some browsers but this will probably be removed in the future - so I wouldn't use it unless you must.
This article shows how to -
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

You can post the json to a server and use the server to generate a download file (ask a new question if thats what you seek)

and finally - are you sure you want to save to file?  if all you want is to save and restore data then there are better alternatives (such as localStorage, cookies, indexDb)

Comment: thanks iftah,i updated my Q after reading your answer. if possible i'd like to know what you think.

Comment: I think this update to the question should be a new question as it is a totally different question (and not a clarification or such).  Leave this question about saving files and start a new question about local storage.

Comment: but to answer your question anyway - local storage is *local* - it will appear only in one computer one browser (ie. if you open the webpage in firefox it will have different local-storage than chrome), and if you open it in firefox in another computer it will have different localstorage again. There is different localstorage for different domains - so you will have same local storage for all webpages under  dl.dropboxusercontent.com

Comment: ok ,just to make sure i understand ,i updated my code to use localStorage. now: 1) when running from different browsers on my desktop ,localStorage is different. 2) when running from the same type of browser,different tabs/windows but loading the same url in dropbox ,i get the same localStorage. 3) when loading the same dropbox URL on my laptop ,i dont see the same localStorage. --> same domain is not enough ,i also need to have the same computer (=location).  right ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes.  The localStorage is stored in the browser, so obviously it can't be the same in different browsers or different computers. The tricky thing is that the browser separates different domains - one domain has only access to its own data. This is a security feature so that evilsite.com script will not have access to data stored by goodsite.com.   But all the open tabs of goodsite.com will have access to the same data.

Comment: btw, there is no need to say "thank you" in stackoverflow.. you can accept the answer (if it answered your question) or vote up (the thank-you's are implied)

Comment: yah ,but i still didnt get the answer i'm looking for :(. i will try to use localStorage for now and see what i can come up with.

Comment: Actually you got your questions answered twice(!). Once about saving files and once (different question!) about using local storage when really it should have been ignored as only one question should be asked. And now you make the same mistake and "update" your question to a totally different question. Why do you do that?  Just open a new question asking about continuing data between different computers. You will get MUCH faster answers if you start a new questions since "new questions" get viewed much more than old questions  (I only viewed the update since you replied to my comment).